# Reorder the objects in the array

Tags: javascript

I have arrays as following

```
var A = ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];
var B = [3, 0, 4, 1, 2];
```

I need to rearrange array A with the given index values in array B. My solution to the problem is following

```
function reArrange(A,B){
  var num; 
  var letter;

  for(var i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
    num = B[i];
    letter = A[i];
    A[num] = letter;
  }

  return A;
}

reArrange(A, B);
```

I get an output of `['D', 'C', 'E', 'C', 'E']` when it should be `['D', 'F', 'G', 'C', 'E']`

Comment: Create a *new* output array: this should make it easier.

Comment: Once you place a different character on an index, its original value is lost. You need to preserve original values.

Comment: Your expected output seems not correct (['D', 'F', 'G', 'C', 'E']). If that's not the case, please explains why your expected output should be ['D', 'F', 'G', 'C', 'E']

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help.

```js
var A = ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];
var B = [3, 0, 4, 1, 2];
var C = []
function reArrange(A,B){
  var num; 
  var letter;

  for(var i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
    num = B[i];
    letter = A[i];
    C[num] = letter;
  }

  return C;
}

reArrange(A, B);

console.log(C)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the second array for the indices for assinging the actual value of the given array.

```js
var array = ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
    order = [3, 0, 4, 1, 2],
    result = order.reduce((r, a, i) => (r[a] = array[i], r), []);

console.log(result); // ['D', 'F', 'G', 'C', 'E']
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and short

```js
var A = ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];
var B = [3, 0, 4, 1, 2];

function reorderAB(first, second){
var result= new Array();
  
  for(var i=0;i<second.length;i++){
    result[second[i]]=first[i];
  }
  console.log(result);
}

reorderAB(A,B);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you replaced array A with new value.

Example with the first i in your loop.
i = 0, num = 3 and letter = C
The original A[3] = F
Then you assign A[num] = letter, mean that A[3] (F) has new value/replaced C and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Map` from `B -> A` and then order the keys accordingly to output your expected array, however I am not sure what use case you are using it for.

```js
const A = ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];
const B = [3, 0, 4, 1, 2];

let bToA = new Map();

B.forEach((a, i) => bToA.set(a, A[i]))

const final = [...bToA.keys()].sort().map(x => bToA.get(x))

console.log(final);
```